# How to access variable from other classes to perform calculation in a class?

Tags: swift, class, object, methods, swift3

I am working with 2 classes to create a Banking system to add and deduct amount from my account. I have two classes one class which I will use to enter my transaction amount and types and another class which I will use to work with the math, like adding and deducting the amount from my account once a transaction is done.

```
class TransactionManager {
    var bal: Int
    init(bal: Int = 0) {
        bal = bal
    }

    func addCredit(entry: Transaction) -> (res: Bool, bal: Int) {
        return (true, balance)
    }

    func deductCredit(entry: Transaction) -> (res: Bool, balance: Int ){
        return (true, balance)
    }
}
```

And my other class is used for entry of transactions

```
class Transaction {
    let description: String
    let credits: Int

    init(credits: Int, description: String = "") {
        self.credits = credits
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

Now I have tried adding some entries like

```
let transactionManager = TransactionManager(balance: 25000)
let transaction = Transaction(credits: 10000, description: "Withdraw")
let a = transactionManager(entry: transaction)
```

I want to modify my code so that when I call this add or deduct method I need to get the total balance added/subtracted with the credit entry I am making via Transaction class.

How can I access the credit amount of the transaction class and use it to perform the math of adding amount or subtracting amount to my actual balance?

Comment: Did you read the answer on your previous question? Perhaps you should spend some time reading the Swift book. Accessing properties from a variable is pretty basic.

Comment: FYI - the `line `bal = bal` won't even compile. You want `self.bal = bal`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
func addCredit(entry: Transaction) -> (res: Bool, bal: Int) {
    self.bal += entry.credits
    return (true, self.bal)
}

func deductCredit(entry: Transaction) -> (res: Bool, balance: Int ){
    self.bal -= entry.credits
    return (true, self.bal)
}
```

Comment: Why don't any of these verify the transaction is valid? What's the point of the `res` part of the return value if you hardcode `true` for all results?